# Android Volley Error: com.android.volley.ClientError

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I would like to know how I can rectify this issue. Research and replacement of code has been done however the problem persists.

Here is my code working with volley.

```
private void Regist(){
    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btn_regist.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final String name = this.name.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = this.email.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = this.password.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                        if(success.equals("1")) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Error!" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Error!" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_regist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return super.getParams();
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Since I receive 'com.android.volley.ClientError' I assume this is wrong but if you require the rest of the code please comment![image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
return super.getParams()
```

By

```
return params;
```